# JAR files not being included with Android Ant build

Tags: java, android

It seems like there are many different answers to this question, none of which work for me!

When I build my android app with eclipse, everything works fine.  My JAR file is located in the `/libs` directory of my project, as recommended.

I am using SDK r15 (the latest android sdk available).

When I run `ant debug`, the apk file is built.  However upon running the file in the emulator, a `force quit` is thrown.  From LogCat, I see errors consistent with the JAR file not being compiled.

Many of the answers I see here, refer to older versions of the SDK.  Also many refer to files which no longer exist.  For example, `android_rules.xml` no longer exists in the `../tools/ant/ directory`.  Instead I see only a `build.xml`.

Has anyone solved this issue for the latest android.

Not I MUST use ant (not eclipse) for this build..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ant to build your android project, just add your jar to the libs project. Eclipse will need you to add it through the project properties wizard. Maven should have some archteyp for that but I don't know it.

An extra jar file needs to be both added through dex and apkbuilder, that's not that easy to do it buy hand, you would be more confortable using ant tools coming with the android sdk, they are pretty well done and provide intersting features like adding jars, build a project for debug and release, testing,etc..

add your jar to a folder named libs and run ant compile from the project basedir.

Comment: Ok, I have a folder called "libs" inside my project base directory.  This directory contains a "gson.jar".  I then cd to the project base directory and run "ant debug" from the command line.  However my emulator still throws "ClassNotFound" exception, indicating that the JAR has not been included.  Please expand on using dex/apkbuilder when you get the chance.  Also, what tool do I use to add jars, examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you use the ant files and targets provided by the android platform ? (android project create ?). It's just a lot of jobs not to use these tools.